# Android: AnimateDrawable cannot be resolved to a type?

Tags: android, animation

So I'm basically copying the code from this project to play around with it: http://code.google.com/p/android-30days-apps/source/browse/trunk/08day/src/com/bakhtiyor/android/snowfall/SnowFall.java?r=27

but I'm running into an issue. On the line drawables.add(new AnimateDrawable(snow_flake, animation)); I'm getting the error message that AnimateDrawable cannot resolve to a type. I've looked around and in the original Android function drawable and animation are passed as one of the constructors. Is there something I'm missing for some kind of configuration?

Here's all of the code that I'm using (I am using cherry_blossom instead of snow flake, but that's the only major difference)

```
private class CherryBlossomView extends View
{
    private int cherry_blossom_count = 15;
    private final List<Drawable> drawables = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
    private int [][] coords;
    private final Drawable cherry_blossom;

    public CherryBlossomView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        cherry_blossom = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blossom_petal);
        cherry_blossom.setBounds(0, 0, cherry_blossom.getIntrinsicWidth(), cherry_blossom.getIntrinsicHeight());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldw, int oldh)
    {
        super.onSizeChanged(width, height, oldw, oldh);
        Random random = new Random();
        Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

        cherry_blossom_count = Math.max(width, height) / 20;
        coords = new int[cherry_blossom_count][];
        drawables.clear();
        for(int i = 0; i < cherry_blossom_count; i++)
        {
            Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, height / 10 - random.nextInt(height/5), 0, height+30);
            animation.setDuration(10 * height + random.nextInt(5 * height));
            animation.setRepeatCount(-1);
            animation.initialize(10, 10, 10, 10);
            animation.setInterpolator(interpolator);

            coords[i] = new int[]
            {
                random.nextInt(width-30), -30   
            };
            drawables.add(new AnimateDrawable(cherry_blossom, animation));
            animation.setStartOffset(random.nextInt(20 * height));
            animation.startNow();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < cherry_blossom_count; i++)
        {
            Drawable drawable = drawables.get(i);
            canvas.save();
            canvas.translate(coords[i][0], coords[i][1]);
            drawable.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();
        }
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd click on the [package above that code you linked to,](http://code.google.com/p/android-30days-apps/source/browse/trunk/08day/src/com/bakhtiyor/android/snowfall/?r=27)
[image]

you'd see that it shows more files.
[image]

AnimateDrawable:

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2008 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.bakhtiyor.android.snowfall;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;

public class AnimateDrawable extends ProxyDrawable {

    private Animation mAnimation;
    private Transformation mTransformation = new Transformation();

    public AnimateDrawable(Drawable target) {
        super(target);
    }

    public AnimateDrawable(Drawable target, Animation animation) {
        super(target);
        mAnimation = animation;
    }

    public Animation getAnimation() {
        return mAnimation;
    }

    public void setAnimation(Animation anim) {
        mAnimation = anim;
    }

    public boolean hasStarted() {
        return mAnimation != null && mAnimation.hasStarted();
    }

    public boolean hasEnded() {
        return mAnimation == null || mAnimation.hasEnded();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        Drawable dr = getProxy();
        if (dr != null) {
            int sc = canvas.save();
            Animation anim = mAnimation;
            if (anim != null) {
                anim.getTransformation(
                                    AnimationUtils.currentAnimationTimeMillis(),
                                    mTransformation);
                canvas.concat(mTransformation.getMatrix());
            }
            dr.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restoreToCount(sc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah awesome, I didn't notice that. Thank you!

Comment: @Sam No new questions were being posted so I kept checking back :-)